# Batch script to remove folders except those ending with a specific value

Tags: batch-file

I try to remove all folders except ones from a list or ending with a specific value.

I've got some ways to remove folders with a specific name, but I'm having issues reversing them to keep folders with a specific name, or part of a name in my case. We are using `sink` in this example.

```
FOR /d /r . %%d IN ("*sink") DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```

I want to keep all folders ending with `sink`, but my code deletes all `*sink` folders.

**EDIT:**

The folders initially are:

```
/home/folder/items/kitchen_sink/
/home/folder/items/bathroom_sink/
```

When I run the script, it removes anything with `Sink` in it. So `/kitchen_sink/` and `/bathroom_sink/` get deleted.

What I am trying to do is keep all folders with the name `sink` in it. Literally the opposite of what my script does.

**EDIT AGAIN:** Looking to keep directories leading up to `sink`.

Comment: The command line `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /C:sink') do rd /Q /S "%%I"` searches with __DIR__ in the __current directory__ only for any directory not being a link (junction, symbolic link) and filters out with __FINDSTR__ all directories in the __current directory__ ending case-insensitive with `sink` and recursively deletes quietly all the remaining directories in the __current directory__ with all their subdirectories. It is unclear from the task description where the folders ending with `sink` exist in folder tree.

Comment: There are no such folders like ``/home/folder/items/kitchen_sink/`` on Windows. A __batch__ file is a script file interpreted by the __Windows__ *Command Processor* `cmd.exe`. Are you sure that you do not mean a __shell__ script file interpreted by [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) on Linux/Mac?

Comment: It makes a big difference if the __batch__ file should delete in `C:\Temp` all directories not ending with `sink` or if it has to recursively traverse through the entire directory tree of `C:\Temp` and delete all subdirectories in each directory level except those containing a directory ending with `sink` anywhere. There is by default always found first `C:\Temp\Folder1` of which name does not end with `sink`, but there could be `C:\Temp\Folder1\Subfolder1\Kitchen_sink` and `C:\Temp\Folder1\Subfolder1\OtherFolder` and `C:\Temp\Folder1\Subfolder2\NoSinkFolder`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

1. If it it is not recursive deletion

   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (
   'dir /a:d ^| find /v /i "_sink"'
   ) do (
   echo rd "%%~fA"
   )
2. If you want to this recursively I think it will be easier to move the "sink" folders to a temporary directory and delete the root folder.

   mkdir "temp_sink=C:\temp\sink"

   pushd "C:\root_dir_with_sink_folders"
   FOR /d /r . %%d IN ("*sink") DO move "%%~fd"  "%temp_sink%"
   popd
   rd /s /q "C:\root_dir_with_sink_folders"

Comment: This did not work, but it did give me some ideas for running another batch test. I'll post here if I get positive results. Please, anyone who might knwo we're still searching.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D /R . %%d in (*) do (
   set "folder=%%d"
   if /I "!folder:~-4!" neq "sink" rd /S /Q "%%d"
)
```

Comment: This worked, however, it deleted all the folders not named "Sink", like it said it would.
The main directories are not called Sink, though. 
Here's some examples of what my directories look like:
`/clients/subclients/utilities/kitchen_sink`
`/clients/utilities/kitchen_sink`
`/upcoming/user/utilities/need/bathroom_sink`

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand you... This code deletes all folders whose _last 4 chars_ are not "sink" (as you clearly see in `if /I "!folder:~-4!" neq "sink" ...` part). In other words, it keeps all folders ending with "sink" as you requested. What exactly is the problem? **`:/`**

Comment: I need to keep sub folders leading up to the Sink.
So `/clients/subclients/utilities/kitchen_sink` is the example, I need to keep `/clients/subclients/utilities/` as well. jsut deleting the other contents inside the `Utilities` folder keeping everything ending with Sink, like you made there.

Comment: This wasn't totally clear. Could you please add several examples of both folders that you want to keep and to delete?

Comment: No. The _important point_ is that you want not just keep the `/clients/subclients/utilities/kitchen_sink` folder, but also _all its parents_ even if they don't ends in "sink". In your example, you want not to delete the folders `/clients/subclients/utilities`, nor `/clients/subclients`, nor `/clients`. You must describe this point in your question because _all commands_ that lists folders (like `for /D /R` or `dir /S /A:D`) _do_ list all the previous folders...